# Break in and break away point

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, pole-zeroplot

Consider the open loop transfer function of \$\frac K{s^3+2s^2+2s}\$.

In a negative feedback system, that has three poles \$0, -1+i ,-1-i\$.

Is there any break-in or break-away point because only one real pole is here? If we solve the derivative of denominator then we get \$s=-0.67\pm 0.47\$ but the points do not lie on real axis.

Please ensure if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: Your approach to what?

Comment: Whether break-in or break-away point exist for this transfer function

Comment: In the root locus ? I don't see any. [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=root+locus+of+1%2F%28s%5E3+%2B+2s%5E2+%2B+2s%29)

Comment: The  root locus goes from 0 to \$-\infty\$ along the negative real axis and the two complex poles enter the right half plane at \$K=4\$. There are no break-in or break-away points.

Answer (score 0):

This is the characteristic equation

```
charEq = s^3 + 2 s^2 + 2 s + K == 0;
```

This is its derivative

```
dcharEq = D[charEq, s]
(*2 + 4 s + 3 s^2 == 0*)
```

And if you solve it you get the result you are getting.

```
sols = NSolve[dcharEq, s]
(* {{s -> -0.666667 - 0.471405 I}, {s -> -0.666667 + 0.471405 I}} *)
```

Any break-away or break-in point must also satisfy the characteristic equation. If you substitute these solutions in into the characteristic equation you will see it is satisfied for only complex values of \$K\$.

```
charEq /. sols
(* {(-0.740741 - 0.209513 I) + K == 0, (-0.740741 + 0.209513 I) + K == 0} *)
```

To correctly formulate the problem you must set the characteristic equation along with its derivative to zero and specify the range of \$K\$.

```
NSolve[{charEq, dcharEq, K >= 0}, {s, K}]
(* {} *)
```

The above formulation will give all the points with multiple roots. Te get the break-away or break-in point on the real axis you must also add an additional condition (this is moot in this example).

```
NSolve[{charEq, dcharEq, K >= 0, s \[Element] Reals}, {s, K}]
(* {} *)
```

Comment: If K is non negetive and real valued parameter, then there is no break-away point...Right?

Comment: Yes, as shown by the last line of code.